# Is there a good python library that provides PGP decryption functionality without the use of a subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, pgp

I am looking for a way to decrypt pgp messages in python without the use of a subprocess. I have checked out http://wiki.python.org/moin/GnuPrivacyGuard but none of those solutions worked. Pyme almost worked except I hit a wall when trying to use set_passphrase_cb to avoid any user interaction but couldn't get it working ( [Problem decrypting PGP in python with pyme without user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660150/problem-decrypting-pgp-in-python-with-pyme-without-user-interaction) ).

The platform is Ubuntu 10.04. What library would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: other the two libraries you mentioned. there doesn;t seem to be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ctypes` to roll your own wrapper around just the parts of GPGME you need.